# Make rotation smooth

Tags: python, animation, pygame

I am making a little game involving rotating parts of chains.   I am new to pygame but here is the start.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import pygame
def draw(square):
    (x,y) = square
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, black, (100+x*20,100+y*20,20,20), 1) 

def rotate(chain, index, direction):
    (pivotx, pivoty) = chain[index]
    if (direction == 1):
        newchain = chain[:index]+[(y-pivoty+pivotx, (x-pivotx)+pivoty) for (x,y) in chain[index:]]
    else:
        newchain = chain[:index]+[(y-pivoty+pivotx, -(x-pivotx)+pivoty) for (x,y) in chain[index:]]

    if (set(chain) & set(newchain[index+1:]) == set()):
        return newchain
    else:
        print "Collision!"
        return chain

pygame.init()

size = [600, 600]
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
white = (255,255,255)
black = (0,0,0)

n = 20
chain = [(i,0) for i in xrange(n)]

screen.fill(white)
for square in chain:
    draw(square)

pygame.display.flip()
raw_input("Press Enter to continue...")
newchain = rotate(chain, 5, 1)
print chain
print newchain
screen.fill(white)
for square in newchain:
    draw(square)

pygame.display.flip()
raw_input("Press Enter to continue...")
```

Is it possible to make the rotation appear smoothly as an animation rather than just jump to the right place in pygame?

Comment: Do it in more than one step.

Answer (score 1):

You should create a function which doesn't change the state to the final, but does a little part of the movement and, if the animation is not done, calls itself with a timeout.

For example (that's pseudo-pygame)

```
f(object):
     object.position.x = 10
```

doesn't make object animate smoothly, but

```
f(object):
     if object.position.x >= 10:
         return
     object.position.x += 1
     setTimer(10, f(object))
```

does.

Comment: How would you do the screen refresh? I currently have screen.fill(white) which doesn't seem very sensible.

Comment: Write another function drawEverything which will draw every object you want and call this function every X miliseconds.

Comment: Should it do screen.fill(white) every time before it updates the drawing?